# Where is the "Enable/Disable translation" value stored in the database?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-fields, drupal-entities

Where is the "Enable/Disable translation" value stored in the database? I haven't been able to find this info anywhere.

Comment: Translation of what? And why do you want to change it directly in DB instead using back-end?

Comment: Nodes. I'm going to change it directly in the DB, I'm going to use whether a node has translations enabled or not to generate a report.